# mysql returning empty set

Tags: php, mysql

Been very frustrating but mysql is returning an empty set for this code (not echoing exists) :

```
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("repository", $con);

$url = stripslashes($url);
$url = mysql_real_escape_string($url, $con); 
$exists = mysql_query("SELECT url FROM sites WHERE url = '$url' LIMIT 1");
 if (mysql_num_rows($exists) == 1) {
    echo "exists";
 }
```

it should not be doing this because I've tested a good amount.

The table consists of one column "url", it is datatype varchar(1000) (the maximum). the url stored for test purposes is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thailand

Comment: echo `$url` just before you fire your query and confirm that it looks like the data in your database?

Comment: 1. Have you performed the **same** query on database? 2. What `mysql_num_rows($exists)` returns? 3. Show us the **exact** query that is generated by your code.

Comment: thats the thing also ...I tried to use this sql query in phpmyadmin...and it still returns empty set

Comment: Might be a case sensitivity issue? As Dave said, check the input and the actual data in the database.

Comment: @Praneet Sharma: well, here is the answer.

Comment: Then we'd need to see the table data as well.

Comment: Well, you simply don't have a row where the URL matches the string you're looking for.

Comment: select url FROM sites shows the row

Comment: Okay, please: 1. Add `echo $url` right before you perform the query, 2. Append the output of this echo to this question, 3. Append a dump of the table in question to this question.

Comment: tried this and getting nothing as well....but the weird thing is this sql statement returns an empty set in phpmyadmin when I copy the value from the table exactly....

Comment: Okay... please do what I asked you to do, or else we won't be able to help you.

Comment: I do not have experience in PHP but should not it be
`"SELECT url FROM sites WHERE url ='". $url."' LIMIT 1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you do as a first step. Remove the `WHERE url = '$url'` from your query altogether and print out `mysql_num_rows($exists)` before using it.

That should be enough to tell if it's one of the two likeliest problems:

- bad URL resulting in no rows being returned; or
- bad row caused by database containing other than you expect.

Based on your comments to date, the former is the most likely. If it turns out you get a row back *without* the `where` clause, you'll have to figure out why your URL is incorrect. This may be a case-sensitivity issue or a padding (size) issue, among other things.

---

If, as you mention in a comment, `like` works where `=` doesn't, then we need to see your data.

Execute (at the DB level):

```
select concat('[',url,']') from sites
```

and show us *exactly* what the output is. Similarly, output the URL being used by the code with something like:

```
print_r($url)
```

immediately before executing the `mysql_query`.

Please append the output from both those commands to your question.

Comment: this ends up working if the where is gone...as I mentioned above.....I use varchar(1000)....should I just use varchar?

Comment: Then it's a case sensitivity problem.

Comment: I don't see how it could be case sensitivity if `like` works where `=` doesn't, since `like` respects case as well. @Praneet, you need to start following advice if you want to solve this problem. I've updated the answer with the _exact_ steps to try.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I don't think `LIKE` or `=` is case-sensitive. It depends on the collation used, according to this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 0):

I do not have experience in PHP programming but should not it be `"SELECT url FROM sites WHERE url ='". $url."' LIMIT 1"` 
Please ignore this if `$url` works inside quotes (`" "`)

Comment: the OP's syntax for the query is valid, your syntax is also valid, but more cumbersome.

Answer (score -1):

That will only check if MySQL only returned exactly one row. Check for

```
if (mysql_num_rows($exists) > 0)
```

assuming there is such data you're checking for, of course. You might want to broaden the search using LIKE and wildcards if you aren't absolutely sure the URLs you're passing are identical.

Comment: I know there is only one row in database though...I checked

Comment: True, I just tend to see that check a lot as a source of many problems.
It's probably the equality check on the string, though.

Comment: @Praneet Sharma: ".I tried to use this sql query in phpmyadmin...and it still returns empty set" vs "I know there is only one row in database though". Do you have a row that fits that condition or not?

Comment: As was asked before, the URL in the database and the URL in the variable must match completely (case, whitespace, ...) if you're using the equality comparator. If they're not identical, you'll have to use LIKE, although I rather see my URLs uniform so you can actually test for equality.