# PHP Mysql query is returning null

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple PHP login function. Within this function, I am checking to see if the user exist by making a MySQL query that is selecting username from a table and counting the number of rows that is returned. I am having trouble with the query returning null when I know for a fact that the table contains the username.

Here is my code.

```
function login($user_name, $password) {
    $db1 = new DB_CONNECT();        
    $db1->connect();

    $query = "SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name = '$user_name'";
    $result = $db1->makeAQuery($query);

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        //check the password
    }
    else {
        //no user exist 
    }
}
```

I know that the username and password that are coming in are OK and I trim for any white spaces before I sent them to the function. I know that the database connection is working because it works on the rest of my PHP code. The only error that I am getting is one that mentions that the mysql_num_rows "expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given"

Database class

```
class DB_CONNECT {
    function connect() {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

        // Selecing database
        mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE, $con) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    function makeAQuery($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());        
    } 
    function close() {
       // closing db connection
    mysql_close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the code for the `DB_CONNECT` class?

Comment: and p.s. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: as above, but also STOP using mysql_* built in functions. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603974/mysql-returning-empty-set

Comment: possible solution to all your problems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826981/php-sql-database-querying-good-practice-and-security/829161#829161 best practices

Comment: There a couple of likely candidates for this problem (and some recommendations of doing it differently) but exactly what does this `makeAQuery()` do?

Comment: can you show this `makeAQuery()` function

Comment: To "know for a fact that the table contains the username" isn't enough, you must run the generated query on phpmyadmin or something and have it return data instead of just assuming, thus isolating the error in the function. Always know that `var_dump()` is your best friend in PHPland.

Comment: as djjjuk said, you should stop using mysql_ use mysqli or PDO. to help test your current situation, insert this after your result =  line: if(!$result)
        die("unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); might help you narrow down the error. i don't think the query is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

`"SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name = '".$user_name."'";`

Also

change this:

```
function makeAQuery($query) {
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());        
}
```

to

```
function makeAQuery($query) {
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());      
    return   $result;
}
```

Comment: The Return statement did it. After all that, I forgot a simple statement.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try removing the spaces between the = in the query.

```
"SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name='$user_name'"
```

Your script may be returning null because the query could not run.

Comment: i can make it `WHERE user_name =   many_space_here      '$user_name'` and it will work

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot MySQL does not care for whitespace.

Comment: With or without spaces, the samething